# grabbing data from an internal file

Tags: iphone, initwithcontentsoffile, initwithcontentsofurl

I'm grabbing data from an external file using NSURL with the code below. If i wanted to grab this data from an internal file in my resources folder how would the code be different.

here's the NSURL code:

NSURL *dataUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://sites.google.com/site/*****/***/file.asc"];
NSString *fileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:dataUrl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

this was my attempt:

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fileName" ofType:@"asc"];
NSString *fileString = [NSString initWithContentsOfFile:path];

thanks in advance

Comment: And... what's wrong with your attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try `stringByExpandingTildeInPath`
something like

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fileName" ofType:@"asc"];
    path = [path stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
    NSString *fileString = [NSString initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Comment: thanks for replying. I tried it, but get a warning: 
'NSString' may not respond to '+initWithContentsOfFile:'

Comment: have you tried "- (id)initWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error"?